# What is meaning of storing a state in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface

I recently came across [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/interfaces.html#derived-class-initialization-order) of Kotlin while studying interfaces. What it says is:

> Interfaces in Kotlin can contain declarations of abstract methods, as
> well as method implementations. What makes them different from
> abstract classes is that interfaces cannot store state. They can have
> properties, but these need to be abstract or provide accessor
> implementations.

**What makes them different from abstract classes is that interfaces cannot store state.**

Somewhat confused with this line. What does **storing a state** in Kotlin mean?

I am aware about Java and so if needed, answer may include Java equivalent.

Comment: State is the values/objects held/referenced by fields (in Java) and properties (in Kotlin). In other words, it's the "data". In Java, you cannot declare instance fields in an interface, but you can in an abstract class. In Kotlin, you cannot have a property _with a [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields)_ in an interface, but you can in an abstract class.